# what should I do to be able to listen to this list?

Tags: racket

what should I do to be able to listen to this list?

```
(define b '(あ い う え お か き く け こ さ し す せ そ た ち つ て と な に ぬ ね の は ひ ふ
              へ ほ ま み む め も や ゆ よ わ を ん ら り る れ ろ にょ びゃ びゅ びょ みゃ みゅ みょ  )


  (define (foo-play l)
    (while (not(null? l)
               (play (car l))
               (set! l (cdr l)))))

  (foo play b)

  ;play: expects to be at the top level in: (play (car l))
```

what should I do to be able to listen to this list?

````
  > あ
  (rsound #<s16vector> 0 48971 44100)
  ...................
  > みょ
  (rsound #<s16vector> 0 31675 44100)

```
````

Comment: That's not the idiomatic way to iterate over a list, Scheme is not a procedural language. Given that you're not doing anything with the value returned by `play` you should do something like this instead: `(for-each play l)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need

```
(require rsound)
```

Firstly.